# Hasse bound for elliptic curves (glitches?)

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Hasse theorem says (in the simplest case), for any elliptic curve $E$ (with integer coefficients), the number of solutions mod $p$ is within $2\sqrt p$ of the number of points of a projective line $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb F_p)$ (i.e. $p+1$)

$$ |p+1-N_p| \leq 2\sqrt p $$

for all $p$ (not just asymptotically). I was playing around with it (by the simplest brute-force calculation) but I encountered a few cases, such as $y^2=x^3-1$, where it just goes over the Hasse bounds by a little bit, for a few primes.

https://beta.observablehq.com/@liuyao12/elliptic-curves-counting-solutions#Hasse

It must be a silly mistake somewhere. Then it is a shameless promotion on my part.

Comment: Are you remembering to count the point at infinity on your elliptic curve?

Comment: Clicking your link gave me nasty flicker, so I couldn't read it. Could you just post, say, the smallest prime $p$ where you think there is a problem?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, is it not true that there is always one point at infinity, so I could just count the number of solutions $(x,y)\in\mathbb F_p$ and add one to it? Um...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, my apologies. For the curve $y^2=x^3-1$, the first problem seems to be at $p=61$.

Comment: How many points do you count for $y^2=x^3-1$ with $p=61$, including $\mathcal{O}$?

Comment: I don't want to try to chase through your code and figure out where you went wrong, but for the curve $E: y^2 = x^3 - 1$, $a_{61}(E) = 14$ while you have it as $16$ (noting that you are actually plotting $-a_p(E)$).

Comment: Thank you all! I'll see where my mistake was.

Comment: I believe my mistake was that I used conditional LHS mod p == RHS mod p, and mod operation sometimes gave a negative number.

Comment: That is a common bane for algebraically trained programmers. I have created interesting bugs assuming that mod p gives a value in the range $[0,p-1]$. The first one was particularly nasty to debug because it caused a GPF (from the era of DOS extenders).